# Are there tests of the existence of false vacuum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum

False vacuum is a hypothesis that there exist a state that is a local minimum, but not the lowest energy state.

Why do we think such a state as false vacuum really exist?

Comment: The Higgs mechanism lends some  credence to this hypothesis.

Comment: @probably_someone Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I'm new to this , but look  up the VEV for the Higgs Field, why should it have a non zero value?